# Terraform pass multiple subnet-ids as a list to another resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is a simplified version of the Terraform config where I'm trying to pass a list of subnet-ids to aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment resource. Is there a way to acheive this?

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"  
}

variable "tgw_id" {
  default = "tgw_aa_bb_cc"
}

variable "vpc" {
  default = "10.10.0.0/16"
}

variable "tgw_subnets" {
  default = ["10.10.1.0/24", "10.10.2.0/24", "10.10.3.0/24"]
}

variable "availability_zones" {
  default = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b", "eu-west-1c"]
}

resource "aws_vpc" "new_vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc
}

resource "aws_subnet" "tgw_subnet" {
  for_each = toset(var.availability_zones)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.new_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = var.tgw_subnets[index(var.availability_zones, each.value)]
  availability_zone = each.value
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "vpc_attachment" {
  subnet_ids = I want to pass the 3 subnet ids created on the previous step as a list
  transit_gateway_id = var.tgw_id
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.new_vpc.id
}
```

I've tried using 'data' block but ideally want to avoid using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **splat** expression:

```
subnet_ids = aws_subnet.tgw_subnet[*].id
```

Comment: That worked thanks. I found another way as well. [for k, v in aws_subnet.tgw_subnet : aws_subnet.tgw_subnet[k].id]